# Multiprocessing on pd.DataFrame did not speed up?

Tags: python, pyspark, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to apply function on a large pd.dataframe on pyspark. My code was post below which uses `multiprocessing.Pool` but is not as fast as expected. It cost the same time as `df.apply(f,axis=1)`.

There shall be some mistakes I didn't notice. I spend my day but find nothing out. That's why I finally come here for help.

```
def f(series):
    # do something
    return series

if __name__=='__main__':
    #load(df)
    output=pd.DataFrame()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    for name in df.colunms:
        res=pool.apply_async(f,(df[name],),callback=logging.info("f with "+name))
        output[name]=res.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

After @Andriy Ivaneyko answers, I also tried this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    #load(df)
    output=pd.DataFrame()
    res={}
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    for name in df.colunms:
        res[name]=pool.apply_async(f,(df[name],),callback=logging.info("f with "+name))
    for name,val in res.items():
        output[name]=val.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I change the number of cores from 4 to 8 to 16, however the function consumes almost the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method blocks until the function is completed, that's the reason for not getting performance benefit. Create list of the ApplyResult objects ( returned by apply_async) and perform `get` when you finish iteration over `df.colunms`

```
# ... Code before
apply_results = []
for name in df.colunms:
        res=pool.apply_async(f,(df[name],),callback=logging.info("f with "+name))
        apply_results[name] = res

for name, res in apply_results.items():
    output[name]=res.get()
# ... Code after
```

Comment: It can work, but doesn't go faster. The first loop to obtain `apply_results` just took several seconds. However the second loop which use `res.get()` took the same time as I use `df.apply(f,axis=1)`. It feels like the code just move the job out of the first loop, doesn't feel like a multiprocess work.